# CRM 2011: How to add JScript Web Resources to Small Popup Form.

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am new to `CRM 2011`. I have a button on ribbon which opens a new small form.

On that small form I need to add `JavaScript` `Web Resource` on 'OnChange' event. Is it possible to do that?

If yes can you please suggest me any thing.

I know how to add `Web Resource` to normal CRM 2011 forms, but don't have any idea about this small popup form.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Can't do that.

A bit longer answer: Can't do that. Sorry.

Long answer: Can't do that. Sorry. Not if it's the built-in, modal pop-up presented by CRM. There are two approaches to proceed here. One pragmatic and one idealistic.

1. Pragmatic approach: rethink. Explain what the task at hand is and maybe someone will suggest a different way to solve the problem.
2. Idealistic approach: force it by any means necessary. You **could** add a web resource that looks just like the pop-up and add a lot of functionality to it. It's possible but it's definitely harder, more complex, significantly error-prone and really **not recommended**. Really not.

Comment: thanks @konrad, I have found an another way to handle this. No going to play with this popup window. Will handle it on form load after pressing the OK button on popup.

Comment: May I ask what the intended behavior is? The task at hand, so to speak.

Comment: Button is converting an activity to case. After converting it opens an popup window to select something. I wanted to validate that selection.  When user press the OK button on popup, it populated that selected value on Case form. So now I am validating that selection on Case form load rather than trying on little popup window.

Answer (score 1):

If the pop-up form is a web resource then you can reference other web resources like you would any HTML page.

If the pop-up is a CRM form, then you may be out of luck.

What are you trying to accomplish?  There may be another approach.